# How can this statement be false? "If $\forall x \in D$, $P(x)$ then $\exists x \in D$ such that $P(x)$."

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm a college student taking a discrete mathematic course for summer. I took midterm last monday and got back grades and solutions for the exam, but I'm still confused with this specific question.

The question is:

> Let $D$ represent a set and $P(x)$ represent a predicate where $x\in D$.
> Is this a true or false statement? Explain briefly.
>
> "If $\forall x \in D$, $P(x)$ then $\exists x \in D$ such that $P(x)$."

And the answer is: *This is a false statement.*

How can this statement be false?

( It's late night so I don't wanna bother  my professor)

Comment: Hint: what if $D$ is empty?

Comment: "If every student who bothers the professor late at night fails the course, then there exists a student who has failed."

Answer (score 4):

$\forall x\in D,\,P(x)$ can be vacuously true. For example, $\forall x\in\varnothing\,(x>0)$ is vacuously true, since $\varnothing$ has no elements, but $\exists x\in\varnothing (x>0)$ is false, since clearly no such element exists.

Comment: Is this whole thing only false for $D=\emptyset$?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish If $D$ is nonempty, then $\exists x_0\in D$, and if $\forall x\in D:P(x)$, then $P(x_0)$, so $\exists x\in D:P(x)$. So I believe the only fringe case is when $D=\varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you. So I had to assume that the set was empty?

Comment: Yes - if $D$ is nonempty then the statement is true, but unfortunately that wasn’t stated as an assumption.